# Issue with modal calling page load each time

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

So i have this panel with a bunch of button/items. each of the buttons are responsible for starting the modal with set values put on it.

My issue is that each time i press one of the buttons the modal pops up with correct content, but the main page does a Page_Load and all my collaps panels collapses and the content refresh and refetch data from the DB.

Im thinking that it has to do with my modal script, but im just not good at understanding javascript xD Tried to force it with if(!IsPostback) etc in the pageload etc but without success.

My modal view:

`<div class="modal   " id="modal123" >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                        <asp:Label ID="title" runat="server" Text="Tittel"></asp:Label>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="article" runat="server" Text="Info"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                        data-dismiss="modal">
                        close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

My modal script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        $("#modal-content").load("pages/modals/density_control.php", function () {
            $("#element").focus();
        });
        $('#modal123').modal('show');


    };
</script>
```

The values for the button on the collapse panel that is pressed:

```
        public void FillFaseTable(Table t, int PID, int lifelineID)
    {

        List<Module> listMod = new List<Module>();
        listMod = DbDataAccessLayer.GetModuleByPhase(PID, lifelineID);
        foreach (var Module in listMod)
        {


            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            t.Rows.Add(tRow);
            TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
            LifelineButton btn = new LifelineButton();
            btn.MID = Module.mid;
            btn.moduleID = Module.moduleID;
            btn.title = Module.title;
            btn.Text = Module.title;
            btn.article = Module.article;
            btn.CssClass = "btn btn-primary btn-block btnConfig";
            btn.Attributes["data-toggle"] = "modal";
            btn.Attributes["data-target"] = "#modal123";
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(this.GreetingBtn_Click);
            tCell.Controls.Add(btn);
            tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        }
    }
```

Buttonclick:

```
        void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LifelineButton clicked = (LifelineButton)sender;
        title.Text = clicked.title;
        article.Text = clicked.article;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
    }
```

Comment: I do think im onto somthing however. I see that i have double loaded it so now i removed the btn.Attributes["data toggle"] and target and only use the script manager. This helps with having issues with double loading. Now however the panel still collapses. I see that the button is of type submit. When i change this to input type to button in html inspect it doesnt collapse/reload anymore. But im not able to set the button to button i c# script. Tried btn.Attributes["input type"] = "button" but it is still submit when i inspect the loaded html.

Comment: Edit fixing it to btn.UseSubmitBehavior = false; (made it type button) didnt help either ><